# Evaluate $\int_C\frac{dw}{e^w-1}$ over some loop C contained in the annulus $0<|z|<2\pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, analyticity, laurent-series

Evaluate $\int_C\frac{dw}{e^w-1}$ (counterclockwise) over some loop C contained in the annulus $0<|z|<2\pi$.

Considering the coefficient of $1/z$ in the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ by long-dividing $\frac{1}{z}(\frac{z}{z+z^2/2!+z^3/3!+...})$, I get 1, which means the contour integral is $2\pi i$. Is there a direct way to evaluate the integral? The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ is $\log(e^z-1)-z+c$, but $\log$ isn't analytic throughout the disk, so the integral isn't necessarily zero.

Comment: Anything wrong with using the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)?

Comment: We haven't covered residue theorem yet... is there a more elementary approach?

Comment: What about Cauchy Integral Formula?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start computing the indefinite integral as you proposed :
$$\int_C \frac {dw}{e^w-1}=\int_C \frac {-e^{-w}}{e^{-w}-1}dw=\log(e^{-w}-1)|_C$$
At this point you have to be careful and use appropriate starting and ending points for $C$ (so that no discontinuity appears during evaluation of $\ f(w):=\log(e^{-w}-1)\ $ on the path).

You may use the [principal branch of the complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) that excludes the [branch cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branch_cuts) $(-\infty,0]$. Here since $e^{-w}-1$ reverts the sign of real values we will have to exclude the interval $[0,\infty)$ from the values allowed for $w$.

Your path should start in your annulus over $\ w=r\ $ (with $0<r<2\pi$), turn counterclockwise around the origin from angle $0$ (excluded) up to angle $2\pi$.

The value of the integral will thus be :
(the definition of the principal value makes in fact unnecessary the limit for the left term i.e. at $2\pi$)
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\operatorname{Log}(e^{-(r-i\epsilon)}-1)-\operatorname{Log}(e^{-(r+i\epsilon)}-1)\right]\\
&=\operatorname{Log}(1-e^{-r})+\pi i-\left(\operatorname{Log}(1-e^{-r})-\pi i\right)\\
&=2\pi i\\
\end{align}

Comment: Note the principal branch means cutting along $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: @anon: yes but the fact that $e^{-w}-1$ is negativ for positive $w$ should transfer it to the other side (oups you are right my formulation is incorrect : I'll rewrite it thanks!).

Comment: What are the odds the OP has already studied branches and stuff if, as he declared, the residue theorem hasn't yet been covered by him? I honestly ask since I think the latter is more elementary than the former, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio: well I didn't suppose that the OP knew about branches previously (from the Wikipedia link he could infer that the principal value of the logarithm is simply the value returned by a calculator that 'jumps' from $r-i\epsilon$ to $r+i\epsilon$)... Anyway he asked for a contour integral so that I supposed that he knew the complex logarithm (or is ready to learn about it from the links). I merely followed the integral approach he proposed (I don't say that simpler/better answers can't be given by using the variable $z=e^{-w}$, the basis of residues or whatever...)

Comment: I agree with that, @RaymondManzoni, and I can't really see any other way to approach this without the wonderful Residies theorem. Just one thing: a closed loop in the given annulus may *and may not* go around zero: in one case the integral is $\,2\pi i\,$, in the other is zero

Comment: You are right @DonAntonio I didn't notice it earlier but he doesn't explicitly say that the loop has to include $0$ (and only once). On the other side he specifies that $|z|<2\pi$ so that the other poles at $2\pi k i$ are excluded.